# MongoDB Aggregation: Counting distinct fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to write an aggregation to identify accounts that use multiple payment sources. Typical data would be.

```
{
 account:"abc",
 vendor:"amazon",
}
 ...
{
 account:"abc",
 vendor:"overstock",
}
```

Now, I'd like to produce a list of accounts similar to this

```
{
 account:"abc",
 vendorCount:2
}
```

How would I write this in Mongo's aggregation framework

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I figured this out by using the $addToSet and $unwind operators.

[Mongodb Aggregation count array/set size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568283/mongodb-aggregation-count-array-set-size)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $group: { _id: { account: '$account' }, vendors: { $addToSet: '$vendor'} }
},
{
    $unwind:"$vendors"
},
{
    $group: { _id: "$_id", vendorCount: { $sum:1} }
}
]);
```

Hope it helps someone

Comment: This may work for sets where cordiality of the set is small enough, but for big data scenarios this won't work (imagine if you had hundreds of thousands of unique vendors).

Comment: This answer solves the big data scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24770233/139721

Comment: Is it really necessary to go back to iterate `$vendors` again? given that fact that we can compute the count of vendors by `results.get("vendors").size();`

Comment: @JerryChin can be used operator `$size` in pipline https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501064/mongodb-aggregation-counting-distinct-fields/49210341#49210341

Comment: This may throw OperationFailure: BufBuilder attempted to grow() exception! any idea to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: This approach causes a problem when you have other fields which you don't want to mess up with $unwind and $group.

Comment: there are a few other problems here, including assuming each account has at least one vendor as well as $unwind which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 27):

I think its better if you execute query like following which will avoid unwind

```
db.t2.insert({_id:1,account:"abc",vendor:"amazon"});
db.t2.insert({_id:2,account:"abc",vendor:"overstock"});


db.t2.aggregate([
{ $group : { _id : { "account" : "$account", "vendor" : "$vendor" }, number : { $sum : 1 } } },
{ $group : { _id : "$_id.account", number : { $sum : 1 } } }
]);
```

Which will show you following result which is expected.

```
{ "_id" : "abc", "number" : 2 }
```

Comment: this assumes every account has at least one vendor

Answer (score 24):

You can use `sets`

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$group: { 
      _id: "$account", 
      uniqueVendors: {$addToSet: "$vendor"}
    }},
    {$project: {
      _id: 1, 
      vendorsCount: {$size: "$uniqueVendors"}
    }}
]);
```

Comment: Note that this will only work as long as all the vendors fit in a document, which is limited to 16MB. Probably fine for most cases, but if there are millions of vendors and/or the vendor ids are long (GUID strings anyone? :-/ ) then I guess the double group is the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

I do not see why somebody would have to use `$group` twice.

```
db.collection.aggregate([ { $group: { "_id": "$account", "number": { $sum: 1 } } } ])
```

Comment: I supposed because they wanted to rename the keys and reformat. But this is,indeed, much better and much effective.

Comment: Is this `distinct count`?

Comment: it is 'select group_id, count(*) from table_name group by group_id', rather than 'select count(distinct group_id)) from table_name'

Comment: this answer is wrong as it assumes that no account will have the same vendor twice (i.e. it assumes that the number of documents for each account is the same as the number of distinct vendors.  Completely wrong.

Comment: this answer yields the number of all documents with the same account. for example: account:"abc", account:"abc", account:"abc", account:"bbb" -> abc: 3, bbb: 1

Answer (score 5):

This approach doesn't make use of $unwind and other extra operations. Plus, this won't affect anything if new things are added into the aggregation. There's a flaw in the accepted answer. If you have other accumulated fields in the $group, it would cause issues in the $unwind stage of the accepted answer.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$account",
        "vendors": {"$addToSet": "$vendor"}
    }
},
{
    "$addFields": {
        "vendorCount": {
            "$size": "$vendors"
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: this answer is identical to @Hett's answer which was added 18 months earlier.

Answer (score -1):

To identify accounts that use multiple payment sources:

1. Use grouping to count data from multiple account records and group the result by account with count
2. Use a match case is to filter only such accounts having more than one payment method

> ```
>   db.payment_collection.aggregate([ { $group: {"_id":"$account" ,
>  "number":{$sum:1}} }, {
>                      "$match": {
>                          "number": { "$gt": 1 }
>                       }
>                  } ])
> ```

This will work perfectly fine,

Answer (score -3):

```
db.UserModule.aggregate(
{ $group : { _id : { "companyauthemail" : "$companyauthemail", "email" : "$email" }, number : { $sum : 1 } } },
{ $group : { _id : "$_id.companyauthemail", number : { $sum : 1 } } }
);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: plus it's fundamentally the same as existing answers.

Answer (score -5):

An example

```
db.collection.distinct("example.item").forEach( function(docs) {
    print(docs + "==>>" + db.collection.count({"example.item":docs}))
});
```

Comment: You should provide a description to describe *why* this works as a solution for the question.  It's also very, very helpful to make the example code use the same data and variable context as the actual question.  This answer would be considered "low quality" on StackOverflow; low quality answers tend to attract downvotes, and may get you banned from answering any more questions.