# Count and group on occurrences of keys and their values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection that looks like this:

```
[{
        "installer": "anthony",
        "tester": "bob"
    }, {
        "installer": "chris",
        "tester": "anthony"
    }, {
        "installer": "bob",
        "tester": "dave"
    }, {
        "installer": "anthony",
        "tester": "chris"
    }, {
        "installer": "chris",
        "tester": "dave"
    }
]
```

I am trying to use `aggregate` so I can count how many times each name appears within each field and retrieve the following result:

```
[{
        "name": "anthony",
        "installer": 2,
        "tester": 1
    }, {
        "name": "bob",
        "installer": 1,
        "tester": 1
    }, {
        "name": "chris",
        "installer": 2,
        "tester": 1
    }, {
        "name": "dave",
        "installer": 0,
        "tester": 2
    }
]
```

This is the query that I have completed so far, the problem is that it returns only the `name` and `installer` count without the `tester` count. I could run this query twice (one for `installer` and one for `tester`) but I would like to find a way how to return both counts at once.

```
db.data.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$installer",
            "installer": { "$sum": 1 }
        },
        "$project": {
            "name": "$_id",
            "installer": 1,
            "_id": 0
        }
    }
])
```

What changes to my query are needed so I can get both the `installer` and `tester` counts of each person?

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501064/mongodb-aggregation-counting-distinct-fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to select whether to pass `1` or `0` to the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accumulator in the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline, and an initial value as an "array" for both fields using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to create a copy of the document for each person.

```
db.data.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "val": ["$installer","$tester"]    
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$val" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "_id": "$_id", "val": "$val" },
    "installer": {
      "$max": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": ["$installer","$val"] },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }    
    },
    "tester": {
      "$max": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": ["$tester","$val"] },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }    
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.val",
    "installer": { "$sum": "$installer" },
    "tester": { "$sum": "$tester" }  
  }}
])
```

To counter the case where a given document could have **both** the same "installer" and "tester" values we actually should aggregate on the "document" per the emitted "val" as a first step. Using the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) inside a [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) accumulator makes this case a "single" document instead of "two", being one for each array entry.

The other case of course is to simply return the "set" of values by applying [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) against the initial list to avoid the duplication in such an instance:

```
db.data.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "val": { "$setUnion": [["$installer","$tester"]] }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$val" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$val",
    "installer": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": ["$installer","$val"] },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }    
    },
    "tester": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": ["$tester","$val"] },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }    
    }
  }}
])
```

I added a document to your source as :

```
{ "installer": "jack", "tester": "jack" }
```

In order to illustrate the result.

As for [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/), it is a "ternary" or `if..then..else` condition, where the arguments are "first" `if` for a condition to evaluate as Boolean, `then` being the value to return when `true` and `else` as a value to return when the condition is `false`.

It can be alternately written like:

```
"$cond": {
  "if": { "$eq": ["$installer","$val"] },
   "then": 1,
   "else":  0
}
```

But the original "array" syntax is a bit more brief to write for simple expressions. Most people would still recognize the "ternary" for what it is, but if you think it makes the code clearer then you can used the "named keys" form instead.

The result of course is the `1` is only returned when the field is present in the document, giving the correct counts:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "jack",
    "installer" : 1.0,
    "tester" : 1.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "dave",
    "installer" : 0.0,
    "tester" : 2.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "bob",
    "installer" : 1.0,
    "tester" : 1.0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "chris",
    "installer" : 2.0,
    "tester" : 1.0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : "anthony",
    "installer" : 2.0,
    "tester" : 1.0
}
```

Adding the initial "array" to the document can alternately be done using [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) if your MongoDB version does not support [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/). The only difference is "explicitly" including the other fields that are required later:

```
{ "$project": {
  "tester": 1,
  "installer": 1,
  "val": { "$setUnion": [["$installer","$tester"]] }
}}
```

And if your MongoDB is still actually older than MongoDB 3.2 which allows that notation of an "array", then you can use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) instead from MongoDB 2.6 and upwards:

```
{ "$project": {
  "tester": 1,
  "installer": 1,
  "val": {
    "$setUnion": [
      { "$map": {
        "input": ["A","B"],
        "as": "a",
        "in": {
          "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$$a", "A"] }, "$installer", "$tester"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}}
```

Again using [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to alternately select which value to present as the array elements.

Also, you really should avoid doing things like adding a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to the end of statements. You can of course do it, but it does mean that all results of the previous pipeline stage are being "run through again" in order to make the additional changes. For something as trivial as changing `"_id"` to `"name"`, it's generally better practice to simply accept that the "grouping key" is called `_id` and leave it at that.

As the result of [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), it actually **is** the "unique identifier" for which `_id` is the common nomenclature.

Comment: Thanks for the response and detailed explanation

Comment: It seems the query doubles the actual numbers, so instead of getting `"installer": 2` and `"tester": 1` for `anthony`, it is returning `4` and `2` respectively.

Comment: This happens when the `installer` and `tester` are the same person, e.g. `"installer": "bob", "tester": bob`

Comment: @dat3450 That's correct of course since this case would create "two" documents due to the `$unwind` result. The solution is to add a intermediary `$group` stage to make such a result a single document instead of two. See the added alterations and explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I had also come up with another solution: to include within `$addToFields.val` a `$cond` that will check if `$installer` and `$tester` are the same and to enter it once only if that were the case.

Comment: @dat3450 Same thing basically. You either create an array of one item or you narrow it down. Been away for the last hour so it was really just what I added in the last couple of minutes since seeing your comments.